# How to save all the extracted data from scrapy while crawling?

Tags: python, scrapy

I am using scrapy to crawl all the links from a website but i am not getting the way to save all the extracted links.

Although i am able to add the extracted links in a python set but i am not able to get that python set because it is declared locally to class function.

```
import scrapy

urllist = set()
class LinkCheckerSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = 'LinkCheckerSpider'
    def __init__(self, allowed_domains=None, start_urls=None):
        super().__init__()
        if allowed_domains is None:
            self.allowed_domains = []
        else:
            self.allowed_domains = allowed_domains
        if start_urls is None:
            self.start_urls = []
        else:
            self.start_urls = start_urls  


    def parse(self, response):        
        print("********************************")
        print("This is output of response.url: "+response.url)
        print("********************************")
        a_selectors = response.xpath("//a")
        for selector in a_selectors:
            if("https:" in str(selector.xpath("@href").extract_first()) or "http:" in str(selector.xpath("@href").extract_first())):
                link = selector.xpath("@href").extract_first()
                urllist.add(link)
                request = response.follow(link, callback=self.parse)
                # yield scrapy.http.Request(url=link, callback=self.print_this_link) 
                yield request 

        print(len(list(urllist)))
        print("********************************")

# # --- run without creating project and save in `output.csv` ---

from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

c = CrawlerProcess({
    'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0',
    # save in file as CSV, JSON or XML
    'FEED_FORMAT': 'csv',     # csv, json, xml
    'FEED_URI': 'output.csv', # 
})
c.crawl(LinkCheckerSpider)
c.crawl(LinkCheckerSpider, allowed_domains=["copperpodip.com"], start_urls=["https://www.copperpodip.com"])
c.start()
```

This code can be easily run using command prompt directly, i am using window 10.

Comment: some function need to be there in class which save the extracted link in CSV file or multiple yield which send the link to save the link in CSV file plus send the request to parse the link to get further links

Answer (score 0):

Just `yield` each link:

```
def parse(self, response):        
    print("********************************")
    print("This is output of response.url: "+response.url)
    print("********************************")
    a_selectors = response.xpath("//a")
    for selector in a_selectors:
        if("https:" in str(selector.xpath("@href").extract_first()) or "http:" in str(selector.xpath("@href").extract_first())):
            link = selector.xpath("@href").extract_first()
            urllist.add(link)
            request = response.follow(link, callback=self.parse)
            # yield scrapy.http.Request(url=link, callback=self.print_this_link) 
            yield request 
            yield {"Link": response.urljoin(link)}

    print(len(list(urllist)))
    print("********************************")
```

**UPDATE**
You need to use URI scheme and absolute path with `FEED_URI`:

```
'FEED_URI': 'file://D:/Tmp/output.csv',
```

Comment: is it storing the extracted data in some variable

Comment: plz add further code what do we do on getting the `yield {"Link": response.urljoin(link)}`

Comment: is there any way to write all the extracted url in a python list

Comment: Hi gangabass r u there?

Comment: Hi gangabass, thanks for your patience, how to make the code to write only allowed domain URL as it is writing other domain URL plus it is writing duplicate URLs

Comment: @RinkuYadav move my `yield` into the beginning of your `parse` method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use logging... https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/logging.html

```
import scrapy

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):

name = 'myspider'
start_urls = ['https://scrapinghub.com']

def parse(self, response):
    self.logger.info('Parse function called on %s', response.url)
```

or output your results to a file. https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/feed-exports.html